# GOOGLE DEVELOPER TOOLS - MEMORY LEAK TRACING

Tags: memory-leaks, heap-dump, google-developer-tools

I’ve been trying to trace memory leaks in a hybrid-app built using ionic. I tried using the Google’s developer tools for the same. When i perform heap dump and try tracing any Constructor value, I get there is a Detached DOM tree is present but when i expand the same and view the origin in Objects in the Retainers tab, I’m not able to find which file the variable is located. With this I’m able to say that there is a memory leakage but not the file where it is located. Is there any way to find the file in which the variable or the array causing the leakage is present.
In below picture, I'm not finding a way as to how to trace the file of the memory leak present:

[image]